# Is it possible to make a ClickOnce Certificate last longer than 12 months?

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce, certificate

Can I make an internally generated certificate/key last longer than 12 months?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an old post, but it worked for me back in the Visual Studio 2005 time frame. My self-generated certificate won't expire for another 50 years or so. :)

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200724080019/http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2005/05/30/41068.aspx)

Comment: Sounds promising - I'll look into it.

Comment: I've also had success with MakeCert.  If you already have an existing cert, you can extend the expiration: http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/how-to-extend-an-existing-certificate-even-if-it-has-expired/